# How do I sort command-line output?

Tags: command-line, unix, sorting, du

I'm trying to use `du` to sort the output by filesize, but it doesn't looks like there's an option for that.

Can I pipe it into another command to handle the sorting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shorter, and more succinct (and no Perl ;) ):

```
du -sm | sort -nr
```

Comment: Gnu `sort` has an option `-h` to sort human-readable SI numbers, with `4K` being smaller than `1M`. It's an option when `-m`/`-g`/`-k` don't work well.

Comment: Nice, +1, you don't need the `*` though, du will run on the current directory by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alias duf='du -sk * | sort -n | perl -ne '\''($s,$f)=split(m{\t});for (qw(K M G)) {if($s<1024) {printf("%.1f",$s);print "$_\t$f"; last};$s=$s/1024}'\'
```